# Como posso transformar o conteúdo de texto em inteiro no c#

Tags: c#

Como é possível eu pegar um arquivo `.txt` e transformá-lo em uma cadeia de inteiros?

Meu programa tem que pegar a matriz que está dentro do arquivo `.txt` e colocar dentro de uma matriz no programa para que eu possa manipular os dados dentro da matriz. A parte do que abre o arquivo eu já fiz, mas não estou encontrando um meio de como transformar a matriz dentro do `.txt` em uma matriz dentro do meu programa. Por favor alguém me ajude.

O `.txt` contem esses dados:

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0

1 0 1 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 1 1 0

0 0 1 0 1 1 0

0 0 1 1 1 1 0

0 0 1 1 1 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Qual o formato de dados no arquivo ? Coloque um exemplo desse arquivo `txt` e o código que já tem para fazer a leitura.

Comment: Sem um exemplo de como ta o texto, fica difícil...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode splitar cada linha do arquivo com o split por '\n' e depois splitar cada linha e ir colocando na sua matriz, como por exemplo:

```
        var matriz = new int[10, 10];
        var texto = File.ReadAllText("Caminho para o arquivo");

        int i = 0, j = 0;
        foreach (var linha in texto.Split('\n'))
        {
            foreach (var letra in linha.Split(' '))
            {
                //verifica se o caracter não é nulo ou vazio
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(letra))
                    continue;

                matriz[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(letra);
                j++;
            }
            i++;
            j = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Leandro, você poderia me explicar o por que do \n por favor

Comment: O caractere '\n' é o responsável por quebrar as linhas do texto, ou seja, quando você está digitando um texto e aperta um "enter" na verdade você adicionou o caractere '\n' ao seu texto, os leitores de texto ao identificarem o '\n' sabem que devem quebrar uma linha. Ao splitar o texto em '\n', você criou um array que contém todas as linhas do seu texto. Deu pra entender?
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_linha